# referring to aliases outside subselect

Tags: sql, scope, alias, calculated-columns

The folowing describes what I want to do with this table
Left is a table from wich I want to caluclate 'current_value' for each Event
Code 1 resets the current_value to value
Code 2 adds value to current_value
Code3 reduces the current_value with value

```
Table Events                        |column to be calculated                                
eventId  deviceId EventCode value   |current_value                              
1          1        1          2    |2                          
2          1        2          1    |3                          
3          1        2          1    |4                          
4          1        2          1    |5                              
5          1        3          2    |3                              
6          1        2          2    |5                              
7          1        1          1    |1                              
8          1        2          2    |3          code 1: set                     
9          1        2          1    |4          code 2: add                     
10         1        2          1    |5          code 3: subtract                        
11         1        3          3    |2
```

My SQL code looks like

```
Select                                                  
    EventId,                                                
    deviceId,                                               
    (select last(value) from Events as E where E.EventCode = 1 and E.DeviceID = DeviceID and E.EventId<EventId) AS LastSetValue,                                                
    (select last(value) from Events as E where E.EventCode = 1 and E.DeviceID = DeviceID and E.EventId<EventId) AS FromEventID,                                             
    (select sum(value) from Events as E where E.EventCode = 2 and E.DeviceID = DeviceID and E.EventId between fromEventId and EventId) AS SumOfAdded,                                               
    (select sum(value) from Events as E where E.EventCode = 3 and E.DeviceID = DeviceID and E.EventId betweein FromEventId and EventId) AS SumOfSubtracted,                                             
    LastSetValue+SumOfAdded-SumofSubtracted as current_value                                                
from Events;
```

This code doesn't seem to work becase in the subselect parts DeviceID looks to be the inside temporary tables DeviceID, when I alias the outside DeviceID this will also not work because it cannot be found. From EventID also has this problem.

Any help what is wrong here would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you descibe (without code) what the "current value" stands for?

Comment: Current_value is the length of a device at the moment it is measured (eventID is linked to a date or time). It is a collection of the initial value plus added lengths and sometimes parts are reduced from the device. Sometimes the whole device is replaced with a new one starting again with a new initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I 100% understand your question, but if I'm reading things correctly, you should just need to alias the outside table like so:

```
Select                                                  
    t.EventId,                                                
    t.DeviceId,                                               
    (select last(value) from Events as E where E.EventCode = 1 and E.DeviceID = t.DeviceID and E.EventId<t.EventId) AS LastSetValue,                                                
    (select last(value) from Events as E where E.EventCode = 1 and E.DeviceID = t.DeviceID and E.EventId<t.EventId) AS FromEventID,                                             
    (select sum(value) from Events as E where E.EventCode = 2 and E.DeviceID = t.DeviceID and E.EventId between fromEventId and t.EventId) AS SumOfAdded,                                               
    (select sum(value) from Events as E where E.EventCode = 3 and E.DeviceID = t.DeviceID and E.EventId between FromEventId and t.EventId) AS SumOfSubtracted,                                             
    LastSetValue+SumOfAdded-SumofSubtracted as current_value                                                
from Events t;
```

Comment: I think that is it but in my real table is like  ...from Events INNER JOIN something on something = somethingelse;   where do I put the alias?

Comment: @hbl - right between `Events` and `INNER JOIN` like `Events t INNER JOIN ...`